# how to display middle name as middle initial if middle name have two words

Tags: php, substr

so i created a form which have middle name field and display the middle name as initial.

`preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/",$data["s_mname"])`

this code works IF the middle name is only one word.. like Snow it will display as S but my problem is if the middle name is 2 words like `De Leon`, `Delos Santos` the initial that will be displayed is DL,DS.. but it should display as D... any idea how to do this..

`SUBSTR($data["s_mname"],strrchr($data["s_mname"], ' '), 1)`

i tried this code but nothing works i just got this from other site..

Comment: `preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/",explode(' ',$data["s_mname"])[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode()` like this:-

```
preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/",explode(' ',$data["s_mname"])[0])
```

Output:- https://eval.in/828658

Comment: @LionSmith  Glad to help you.

Comment: yeah.. it takes 10mins to make it as an answer.. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\s\w/', $data["s_mname"], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
/*echo end($matches)[0];*/
echo $matches[0][0];
```

Try this code, and you can use it as per your need